# how I can insert bulk data to database which duplicate records ignored automatically

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, repository, repository-pattern

I'm fetching myriad records from a web service and am want to store them in local DB. perhaps there maybe some duplicate records so I'm checking record by record to find duplicate ones and not store them.
Is there any fast solution such that I give the bulk data to DBMS and it stores those records which are not exists in DB?
It's worth noting that I'm using repository pattern in my ASP.NET web application.

Comment: The records you want to insert, are they in memory or do u store them in a temp table ?

Comment: If you're performing bulk insert, always insert into temporary table first. Only then perform actual insert.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [MERGE statement](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx).